# Control Port Forwarding on Second Router

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, pfsense

Basically, I want my WAN 1 connection port forwarding to be managed entirely by PfSense. Please note there is no option/possibility for me to remove the ISP router for WAN 1. Will it be possible if I forward all ports on ISP Router WAN 1 to PfSense WAN 1 IP 192.168.0.191 then let PfSense manage the rest of the port forwarding?

Basically, the end goal is to delegate port forwarding duty of ISP router to PfSense.

Please see my setup in this image:

[image: Please see my setup in this image.]

Comment: There isn't an option. Will it work if I forward ALL TCP/UDP port from 1~65535 to my pfsense WAN IP of address?

Comment: Yep, pretty much the same. throughput test it, as you are technically still nating on two devices.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart What details do you mean?